# How to install PDO driver for PHP 5.5 to access Posgres on Mac?

Tags: php, macos, postgresql, pdo

I have PHP 5.5.36 running on Mac (OSX 10.10.5) and install the PDO driver with

```
brew install homebrew/php/php55-pdo-pgsql
```

However, running the line

```
$dbh = new PDO("postgres://localhost:5432");
```

generates the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /Users/zaitsev/tests/pg-php/pdo-test.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/zaitsev/tests/pg-php/pdo-test.php(2): PDO->__construct('postgres://loca...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/zaitsev/tests/pg-php/pdo-test.php on line 2
```

Is there anything else needed to install the driver?

Comment: [Postres/PDO DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php)

Comment: @LucasKrupinski Thanks, is there any complete usage example making a query and printing out?

Comment: The PDO documentation for [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) has an example in the comments, but at that point, any PDO example "should" work, so long as the query doesn't use syntax that Postgres doesn't understand.

Answer (score -1):

You must enable the pdo driver in your php.ini file.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: open a terminal window and search for the file php.ini and open it with vi or nano.  search in dynamic extensions and you will find pgsql which you should uncomment.

Comment: Wasn't that simple - I had to add the full entry: `[pdo_pgsql]
extension="/usr/local/opt/php55-pdo-pgsql/pdo_pgsql.so"`